# iPhone Today View for Apple calendar Whats Up Next showing wrong time

Tags: iphone, ios, ical

so I use apple calendar set to local time and keep events in local time.  I've noticed when using the Today View from the home screen, events that show the correct time in the calendar app show the incorrect time in the Today View.  Below are screen shots - 1 from the calendar screen, look at the AA 1455 flight that shows the correct time of 2048 then the Today View that's 2 hours off, 1848.  Does the Today View get its time from a different source than the calendar ?  How can I get the Today View to show the correct time?  This seems to happen when im traveling....  iOS 13.3

[image: cal]
[image: screen]

Comment: Up Next and the Calendar widget are two different things. Does the problem appear on both of them?

Comment: so I use apple calendar set to local time and keep events in local time. I've noticed when using the Today View from the home screen, events that show the correct time in the calendar app show the incorrect time in the Today View. Below are screen shots - 1 from the calendar screen, look at the AA 1455 flight that shows the correct time of 2048 then the Today View that's 2 hours off, 1848.

Comment: I've noticed the Today widget takes a few seconds to update its display at times.  Have you left it there for a few seconds to see if it updates to the correct time?  Also, there's many good free calendar for iOS, I use Readdle's Calendar 5, have you tried any of them?

Comment: yes and no.  Id like the apple stuff to work.  just wanted to make sure im not doing anything wrong.  Looks like a defect in the program.   Apple can't figure it out either,

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's a time zone issue if you're travelling a lot between time zones.

Does it help to go into the Calendar settings in iOS and set Time Zone Override? I'm not sure how it works, but worth having a look at it. Additionally, you can also set the time zone for individual events for particular time zones.

I've attached a screenshot of the Time Zone Override screen in the Calendar settings on iOS. [image]

Comment: so I have all calendars to keep event times constant. so that for instance 5pm stays 5pm no matter where I am.  which is good for me.  but I cannot understand why all other things being equal, if you look at the above example for flt 1455 the start times are different.  the correct time is 2048 which shows in the calendar app.   The today view always shows the incorrect times when traveling which is confusing when I travel because its always off.